# How should I document class and object attributes using Numpy's style?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

I've been reading through [Numpy's documentation standards](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt), and it doesn't seem to make a mention of object attributes - only class attributes.

So, for instance, how would I document the following?

```
class ClassA(object):
    """Short description of ClassA

    Long description of ClassA

    Parameters
    ----------
    param : param_type, optional
        param_description

    Attributes (class)
    ----------
    class_attr : class_attr_type
        class_attr_description

    Attributes (object)
    ----------
    obj_attr : obj_attr_type
        obj_attr_description

    """

    class_attr = 'something'

    def __init__(self, arg='something else'):
        self.obj_attr = arg
```

EDIT:
Just wanted to note that I'm switching to [Napoleon](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which says it supports attributes, but not specifically class or instance attributes.

Comment: The difference between "class" and "object" attributes in python are pretty subtle so I think the difference is glossed over in the standards. Take a look [here](http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) for a discussion of how class and instance attributes don't behave as many would expect them to in python.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried what is mentioned in the [How to Document](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt#class-docstring) file provided in numpy. It mentions the documentation of class attributes should be handled as follows.

> An Attributes section, located below the Parameters section, may be used to describe class variables:
>
> ```
> Attributes
> ----------
> x : float
>     The X coordinate.
> y : float
>     The Y coordinate.
> ```

It goes on to mention that instance properties should have their own documentation and only be listed by name.

That makes sense but I can't find any examples of this in the numpy source code. The closest I found did something different in [ABCPolyBase class](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/192f025ce5280dffbdd361e3ee0645aa08764156/numpy/polynomial/_polybase.py).

```
Attributes
----------
coef : (N,) ndarray 
...
Class Attributes
----------------
maxpower : int
```

In my opinion, the documentation used in the `_polybase.py` class is legible but I do not believe the `Class Attributes` usage will work with Sphinx autodoc summaries.

I hope this information is helpful.

Comment: Good digging - thanks! I was wondering why instance attributes should be left undocumented – I find those a lot more useful than the class attributes (especially since, as @Bi Rico showed, instance attributes supercede class attributes).

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm going to have to extend Napoleon to be able to use Class or Instance Attributes - it doesn't look like they list those separately in their documentation:

http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: There is an opened issue on Sphinx about the confusion documenting class and instance attributes: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3141